# Identify font in Windows 7 shutdown with updates screen

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif, windows-7

I'm designing a Windows 7 shutdown with updates screen which resembles the stock Windows 7 screen as close as possible.
The stock screen shows a message: "Installing updates. Do not turn off your computer.", see this (in German):

[image: Windows shutdown with updates message]

Which font is this?

From Identifont I'm assuming it's Verdana, 21 pt.
Can somebody please verify this?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: I edited my question to match the requirements, but it was downvoted anyway. Is there still something wrong with my question?

Comment: Perhaps because you could probably figure out yourself by doing some research and testing a few fonts... Research is one of the requirements for font-ident questions.

Comment: Well I did with several pages from the reqirements list. I ended up with Identifont, telling me it is "Nina", a Verdana derivative. I tested on my system with Verdana, which is the only font on my Windows system coming close to it, but with some differences in kerning.

Comment: It's almost certainly not Verdana. Compare it with Verdana and you can clearly see the differences: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZmi8.gif ...then compare it with Segoe UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScoYM.gif (there are small differences but that's most likely down to hinting, the low-quality screen and the dodgy version I had to use for testing it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain but I believe it is Segoe UI (Version 5.01), which a quick search shows that Windows 7 used for most of its UI.

[Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines – Fonts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742483.aspx)

[Segoe UI - Version 5.01](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1792)

[image]

Compare your screenshot...

[image]

and the same typed out in in Segoe UI...

[image]

The quality on your screenshot isn't great and I had to test it by typing it out on a live preview on a font website so there are differences but the proportions are (close enough to) identical and I'd assume the message uses the same font as the rest of the Windows 7 UI.

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed Segoe UI. The links provided gave me very helpful insights on using UI text - not only in font style, but also in other aspects, like wording.